# Using several MYSQLI Prepare and fetch

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to show A result which requires Two previous queries; and as I am trying to do this stuff with the new Mysqli interface, I don't get it to work in the right way.

I have this, and the output is: **Warning: mysqli::prepare() [mysqli.prepare]: All data must be fetched before a new statement prepare takes place**

```
$qryRdmPh="SELECT `id` FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,30";
$stmtRdmPh = $mysqli->prepare($qryRdmPh);
$stmtRdmPh->execute();
$stmtRdmPh->bind_result($id);
 while($stmtRdmPh->fetch()) {
 //Obtener el atributo Frase
 $qryPhVal="SELECT `id_v` FROM `values` WHERE `id_p`='" . $id . "'";
 $stmtPhVal = $mysqli->prepare($qryPhVal);
 $stmtPhVal->execute();
 $stmtPhVal->bind_result($idV);
  while($stmtPhVal->fetch()){
  echo $idV;
  }
 }
```

There must be another way to show results without so complex rules... I've read it's very important to use Statement queries, but why? It makes my code just much longer and more complex.

**Edit**: I would really thank if someone explains me if statements are so important as said, and if I should use them always.

Comment: Anytime you're doing nested queries where the inner query is fetching things based on a result from the outer query, you should SERIOUSLY consider using an [SQL join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Comment: @MarcB in this case, I need a SET of results for each SINGLE Id returned by the frist query. I don't think I can do any join there.

Comment: so? anything two nested queries can do, a joined query can do better. `select id from table left join values on values.id_p=table.id order by rand() limit 0,30`.

Comment: @MarcB I did not know about the possibility of JOIN. I could JOIN Three tables, just great :) On the other hand, when should I use statements or not, and why?

Comment: in this specific case, prepared statements are not strictly necessary, since you're just passing around an ID number. but as a general rule you should always use them - anytime you're putting something "dynamic" into a query. even if you know the data should be safe because you generated it, you can still very easily inject yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **always a possibility to do the same thing without nesting queries** in this way. And what's more... if you are doing it this way, it may harm your DB. Always try to get a simplier way.

**For example**: If you want to do queries which depend on a current query, it would be better if you make a buffer and insert all rows after buffering.